# Get properties of the application referencing a C# class library from the library

Tags: c#, class-library

What I'm trying to accomplish is this; I have a class library I've made, but I want to be able to detect which application is using it since I have several applications using one library, but I want to be able to make certain functions available to one application and not have them available to any other applications, all while only having a single standalone class library. The information I'd like to be able to retrieve when the class library is referenced or called upon by an application is; the application name, version, and if it is signed.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Eww. I don't like the sound of this. How exactly are some functions made unavailable? Throwing an exception or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` to find the entry point for an application (eg. the executable assembly that was originally run).

```
Assembly caller = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
var name = caller.GetName();
var version = name.Version;

// etc.
```